# IMU for measuring body movement in water

Tags: sensor, filter, imu, underwater, movement

As a swimmer I have always been curious to use my engineering knowledge in this sport. Specifically I do finswimming like the video I show below :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckKeR5EVWkk

I would like to be able to obtain the movements of swimmers, in particular the movement of the fin, including sensors and devices capable of making these measurements.
The first thing that came to my mind is the use of IMUs but I don't know to what extent this could work. I haven't seen anything like that already done on the market so I was wondering what it is that makes them not to manufacture or use motion sensors from IMUs. I have seen a lot of cameras being used that track the motion of the person but not specifically just a sensor that from that you can get the motion measurements.

I guess they may be for some of the following reasons:

- The problem of obtaining initial conditions (which in this case can be solved by telling the swimmer to hold still for a time lapse before starting to swim).
- The numerical integration includes errors.
- IMUs devices have very high measurement errors (of which I am not very sure).

I would like to know if the proposal I propose is possible and in what way it could be carried out, what devices would be recommended for this task, if the PCB design would be needed or there are already boards focused on these tasks.

PS: Take into account the data, should be stored in the internal memory of the microprocessor, a memory card or even that the sensor is under water and through a cable is connected to the microprocessor that is outside (this makes transmission protocols such as I²C that have a limit of about 2 meters do not work). I believe that wireless systems will not work to send information from underwater to a device that is outside.

Thanks to anyone for any help they can give.

Comment: Just an idea... Get a waterproof phone. Install an acceleration-recording app - there are free ones that produces graphs of g against time. Strap the phone to your foot. Swim. Does the graph look interesting? Useful? That would be a good start before you try designing anything special.

Answer (score 2):

I did fin swimming with the monofin some decades ago, I am an electronic engineer too and I own a Garmin Forerunner 735.

If I do fast turns at the pool wall, the Forerunner worn at the wrist recognizes each turn pretty well even when I use my arms for crawl strokes. (Swimming dual fins)

So I think IMUs like that used in the Forerunner may recognize a minimum and maximum of the vertical acceleration when worn at the ankle joint. So the fin stroke frequency should be measurable using numerical differentiation.

Measuring fin stroke amplitude requires double numerical integration with compensation of the earth gravity acceleration. So I think the amplitude measurement should be more difficult than stroke frequency.

Measuring the horizontal speed of swimming requires a single numerical integration with clever offset compensation. When done in a swimming pool on distances of several 100 m, offset errors may be found by comparison of speed in both directions.

When distances are measured, the results may be compared to the pool length.

I think I will ask a much younger and fitter fin swimmer than I to swim about 200 to 400 m with my Forerunner and to measure the time for each 50 m interval with a stop watch and compare the results.

But building a waterproof electronic with IMU, processor and memory in a small single case like the Forerunner is not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a wearable device for measuring the mechanics of fin-swimming (which I find to be a fascinating biomimicry of a fish) should be practically achievable. If you're mainly interested in the fin's motion, one device could accomplish it. If you want to know everything the legs and arms are doing, you're going to need devices strapped onto the limbs, and keeping things synchronized would add complexity.

It would need an IMU, combining 3-axis accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer, operated at a fairly high data rate -- let's guess 100 samples/sec. The resulting data stream would be processed by a fusion algorithm to combine the strengths of the sensors while minimizing their weaknesses. The output would include the position, acceleration, angle, and angular rotation of the device. The software to accomplish this isn't easy, but it's been done. You may even be wearing this code on your wrist already.

Sending the data wirelessly in real time to poolside would be a challenge, though. If acceptable, it would be much easier to accumulate the data in the device's RAM or flash memory, then download it after the swim.

This isn't a shopping site, but if you search for "mbientlab" you'll find one commercial source for wireless IMUs for experimenters. You'd just need a waterproof enclosure and attachment to the fin.